# Defining and declaring the functions/methods in the c++ .h file

Tags: c++, header-files, logging

I want to know that if i can define and declare methods/functions in a .h file and whether i could call them in a test file(.cpp file)or do i need just to declare in the .h file and the deine in a separte .cpp file.

Thanks
 i am coding in c++

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

You can declare and define functions in a header but defining them without making them **[inline](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html)** might give you linking errors.The **[one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)** is easy to break unless the functions are `inline` in the latter case.

Unless, You really know what you are doing it is best to declare the functions in a header file and define them in a cpp file.

Comment: :if i have a function as 
int DateFormat(struct tm* tm)
{
....
return atoi(date.c_str());
}
i can declare in the header file but what arguments to pass in it

Comment: You declare it in a header file, include the header file in the cpp file from which you want to *call* the function. Declaring a function, Defining a function body & actually calling a function are three different milestones.You do really need a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: :if in that function defination i have got several variable and if i do according to u as said that defining in cpp file where should i give the declarations f the variable

Comment: @gandhigcpp: I already did that. Check the links I have added in the answer as well as the comment.